# How do I remove the pop-ups on shadowplay/ Nvidia share?

Tags: nvidia-geforce-experience, shadowplay

Whenever I want to record for my youtube channel, these pop-ups show up in my recordings. How do I disable them, or stop them from popping up?

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable the ShadowPlay notifications you have to go into the settings, there is a whole section about notifications, then you can just disable all of them or some of them.

[image: ShadowPlay menu]

[image: ShadowPlay settings]